# Parameterized query in Postgresql with a json array

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres, pg-promise

I would like to invoke array_prepend into a json[] using a parameterized query. I am using pg-promise npm package but this uses the normal node-postgres adapter under the hood.

My query is:

```
db.query(`update ${schema}.chats set messages =
  array_prepend('{"sender":"${sender}","tstamp":${lib.ustamp()},"body":$1}',messages) where chat_id = ${chat_id}`
 , message));
```

Same with "$1".

It works with a non-parameterized query.

Above code produces :

> { [error: syntax error at or near "hiya"]

Main reason for this is to avoid sql injection (docs say that they escape adequately when using the parameterized queries).

Comment: 1. Make sure to upgrade to the latest pg-promise; 2. Replace `${schema}` with `${schema~}` to generate a proper SQL name. See also: [SQL Names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names)

Comment: I think there is a mix up. ${schema} and all other ${vars} don't come from user input and and are es6 templates. 

Changing the query to $1~ resolves the error. Can you affirm that this query is now sql injection resistant with adding only the $1~ ? Thank you

Comment: You are getting the positive result by breaking the formatting twice, - the second error breaks the first one so that the result works. You should not use an approach like this, it is wrong all the way. See the example I provided in my answer.

Comment: yes you were too fast :)

Comment: And to your question about SQL injection. If you inject query values with the standard variables, while SQL names with the names syntax - as I showed in my answer, then all your strings always end up inside quotes, and all your sql names end up inside double quotes, making it impossible to mutate the query in case of an SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your query.

The first one is that you are using ES6 template strings, while also using sql formatting with `${propName}` syntax.

[From the library's documentation](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#named-parameters):

> Named Parameters are defined using syntax $*propName*, where * is any of the following open-close pairs: {}, (), [], <>, //, so you can use one to your liking, but remember that {} are also used for expressions within ES6 template strings.

So you either change from ES6 template strings to standard strings, or simply switch to a different variable syntax, like `$/propName/` or `$[propName]`, this way you will avoid the conflict.

The second problem is as I pointed earlier in the comments, when generating the proper SQL names, use what is documented as [SQL Names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names).

Below is a cleaner approach to the query formatting:

```
db.query('update ${schema~}.chats set messages = array_prepend(${message}, messages) where chat_id = ${chatId}', {
        schema: 'your schema name',
        chatId: 'your chat id',
        message: {
            sender: 'set the sender here',
            tstamp: 'set the time you need',
            body: 'set the body as needed'
        }
    }
);
```

When in doubt about what kind of query you are trying to execute, the quickest way to peek at it is via `pgp.as.format(query, values)`, which will give you the exact query string.

And if you still want to use ES6 template strings for something else, then you can change the string to:

```
`update $/schema~/.chats set messages = array_prepend($/message/, messages) where chat_id = $/chatId/`
```

That's only one example, the syntax is flexible. Just remember not to use ES6 template string formatting to inject values into queries, because ES6 templates have no knowledge about how to properly format JavaScript types to comply with PostgreSQL, only the library knows it.

Comment: is this query now sql injection proof no matter what the sender inputs as body for example?

Comment: I answered this moments ago in a comment under your question :) And yes, your `body` is a text string, will always be inside single quotes, which makes  it impervious to SQL injection. SQL injection cannot mutate queries through quoted values or quoted SQL names, only through open ones. So if you are using the default formatting provided by the library, you are safe ;)